# IF Function in Excel (or any other function that would work better)

Tags: microsoft-excel

I am looking to create an IF function using dates and want to fill expiration column `J1` to be 5 years after the latest date applicable.

*Below is what I want to returned in J1.*

If Date 3 `I1` is Not Blank, then return Date 3 plus 5 years.

If `I1`is blank, then I want it to return Date 2 `G1` plus 5 years.

If Date 2 `G1` is blank, then I want it to return Date 1 `D1` plus 5 years.

Below is the  formual I have tried so far and it returns with a “#value!” error.

```
=IF(I1="",IF(G1="",DATE(YEAR(D1)+7,MONTH(D1),DAY(D1)),DATE(YEAR(G1)+7,MONTH(G1),DAY(G1))),DATE(YEAR(I1)+7,MONTH(I1),DAY(I1)))
```

Can some one help me to fix the issue?

Comment: The formula works ok here. Have you doublechecked that the date cells really are either empty or has date values (not as text but as serial day numbers, although possibly formatted to represent dates)

Answer (score 1):

*You can try this formula also:*

```
=IF(AND(I1<>"",ISNUMBER(I1)),DATE(YEAR(I1)+5,MONTH(I1),DAY(I1)),IF(AND(G1<>"",ISNUMBER(G1)),DATE(YEAR(G1)+5,MONTH(G1),DAY(G1)),IF(AND(D1<>"",ISNUMBER(D1)),DATE(YEAR(D1)+5,MONTH(D1),DAY(D1)),"No date")))
```

**How it works:**

The formula checks whether the respective Cell are Not Blank and has Serial number (basically used for Date) then Adds 5 to the Year, to get Expiry Date.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `IFS()` quite nicely for this kind of formula. Not only can you lay it out like you see below, looking like that in Excel's Formula Editor, which is nice in itself as, since Excel 2007, you can drag the bottom of the Formula Editor window down to be as many lines as your screen has room for, not just three, and therefore you can see it laid out entirely instead of having to scroll it which means each "test" can appear on a line by itself making it easy to see the logic you are applying, both to understand it a year from now and to make editing it or turning it over to someone else easy, no, not only this, but it the making of its logic easy to understand and edit is a big thing in itself when writing the spreadsheet.

So:

```
=IFS(
     AND(I1<>"", ISNUMBER(I1)),  EDATE(I1,12*5),
     AND(G1<>"", ISNUMBER(G1)),  EDATE(G1,12*5),
     TRUE,  EDATE(D1,12*5)
    )
```

`IFS()`, laid out this way, makes it much easier to add in new conditions to test, and makes where they go much clearer. Same goes for deleting conditions.

In it I have used `Rajesh Sinha`'s improvement of the basic `IF()` you used, that of not just testing the cells for not being blank, but also testing that the data entered in them is a number. That's about as close as you can come to being sure someone entered a date in the cell you are about to use. You could do more, but his test is a "no matter what, if it fails, you have wrong data entry" while the other things are speculative, as in "ought to be right, so testing it succeeds ought to be a good test" which could end up with a few mistakes due to weird entries.

Given that the use of the formula seems like there could be money involved, using his second test seems like a very good idea.

I noticed that in your formula, you go at it in the opposite way from what these two answers do:  we both look at it as look at I1 and expect success, etc. down to D1. So we both use the logic of:  IF( test1, do if successful, do if it fails ) and our test is written to "hope for" a successful result. So we write `IF( I1<>""` so we see the next thing as the immediate result rather than `IF( I1=""` which does not show the good result of the first test succeeding immediately but rather send you into the rats' nest of "OK, well, then test this, and then this, and then this" before finally reaching what the first thing was aiming at at the end of it all.

The result for the first thing succeeding is at the end of all that, or "buried" so to speak. USUALLY, formulas are much more understandable later, even at the time, if that first test's happy result has its outcome immediately following.

In other words, test for I1 NOT being blank so you have an immediate result in the TRUE spot, and the rats' nest never need think about it again if the result you really wish to test fails. Then each piece of logic stays together inside the formula and you do not have to scan inches of arcane material looking for the one more bit that goes with the stuff at the beginning.

I say "USUALLY" because, like everything with humans, if you try the way both these answers did it and flat out do not cotton to it (really do try though), then it may well be that however nicely it works for others, it is just foreign to you and the way you did it is clear as a bell. People do differ.

I have seen this before and often enough get some feedback and it turns out the person doing it has some programming training or does it professionally. And draw from that (not necessarily correctly) that when programming professionally, there is an advantage to this approach. Who knows though? I've never gotten feedback at the second level, only the first.

However, if it is not something that works best for you due to how your brain is "wired," I would point out that this approach has a big to large to HUGE advantage in Excel:  Excel takes apart a formula and picks the place to start, laying out the pieces in a trail it will follow until done with them. So, 50 calculation elements means 50 calculations right? Not so. The moment Excel realizes it has reached the final result it stops. So if it had to do only 9 of those 50 calculations to get there, it only does 9, not all 50. Multiply gains like that over 1,000, 100,000, and so on rows and in multiple columns, and you can see a very large gain in performance. The days of Excel choking and you having to restart your computer ended between 2001 and 2010, but who wants even a five second delay on every press of Enter? I promise, that can be very, very bothersome. So writing the formula so that success at the first place tested, rather than forcing it through ALL steps if that first bit was a success or not, can be a very nice benefit. So I recommend that if you can make that way of approaching `IF()`'s feel right, do so.

Personally, I hate `SWITCH()` for some reason. It seems utterly non-Excel-ly. When writing what will never not be a small spreadsheet (trickier to always be sure of that than you would think), I just grunt out the `IF()` or `IFS()`. But if it will get middlin' to big or have a larger than usual number of formulas, I admit some `IF/IFS` work runs a lot faster when one converts them to a `SWITCH()`. Not often at all, and not even 1% of what Excel's advertising about it when launched claimed, and not fitting for anywhere near any regular `IF/IFS`, but once in a while, it really is a calculational savings, though not usually a logic savings. Take away 10 `IF()` tests in a formula that is fitting for a single `SWITCH()` with maybe it needing one more function to set up for it, and you've cut calculation down to 20%. Multiply by 80,000 rows and... it's a savings. I hate it, but it's worth doing.

I hate even more that I hate the function, but I can't figure out why so I can't work on that. But I'll still use it when savings matter.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).